# Populate Datatable from ajax json

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

My table is not populating. I can see that it is getting the correct JSON

JSON Data received looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "FooBar",
    "predicted": "0",
    "points": "1",
    "section_id": "1",
    "detail_alias": ""
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

HTML

```
<table id="example"></table>
```

JS

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "ajaxSource": "rest/index.php?m=foo",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "id" },
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "detail_alias" },
        { "data": "points" }
    ]
} );
```

All I'm seeing in my browser is:

[image]

It says "Loading..." when the network tab shows that the call had a 200 response with the correct data.

Why isn't the table populating?

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html - have you even looked at the documentation? It looks **very** different from your example. According to this, your data structure is wrong, to say the least.

Comment: Yes, although this documentation better fits my needs: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data#Examples (you can name columns to match the data)

Comment: I see. Well, this is awkward. I ahve only limited experience with datatables and happened to be familiar with the documentation I linked. However, I've never seen the documentation you've linked before, so in that case, I guess I have nothing to add, sorry!

Comment: any warnings thrown in console by plugin?

Comment: @charlietfl -  Funny I didn't think to look as some of the previous errors I've fixed gave alerts with details about what was wrong. I am seeing this `jquery.dataTables.min.js:48 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: have to use development version to see what that is specifically being caused by

Comment: Seeing the other examples that show the full json context, I figured that it wants me to encapsulate my data in a `data` property. So the 0 undefined was probably the `data`. It now works if I do that... but that screws up some of my other calls... will have to find another way.

Comment: was able to get this to work: http://pastebin.com/LNFvDkQG, actually preferable for me to get the data with $.ajax as it gives me more flexibility.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So the `ajaxSource` in my question was expecting data to be formatted as such:

`{ data: [ { ...`

And I didn't want to have to modify my back end to send data in this format as it would cause problems in other places. I'm assuming other people that end up on this page looking for a solution will likely have the same issue.

My solution was to get the data via `jQuery.ajax()` and then pass it in to the `aaData` field, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    'url': "/rest/index.php?m=foo",
    'method': "GET",
    'contentType': 'application/json'
}).done( function(data) {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "aaData": data,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "detail_alias" },
            { "data": "points" }
        ]
    })
})
```

This allows me to not have to worry about changing the json data from the format in the question.

I like this way better anyway as I feel it gives me more flexibility if I wanted to do modify or use the data for anything else at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. This works for me. But I've to ask you that what if some column value is empty or null? How to check?

Comment: It's been so long, and I haven't used datatables since... but I'd imagine it would handle empty/null data fine? what happens? do you have a specific issue or concern?

Comment: yes the datatable handling the empty/null values. But I want to show if some column value has an empty or null value then I want to show static content i.e 'N/A'.

Comment: I think I would just map empty/null to "N/A" before feeding to datatable.

Answer (score 2):

Followup the below style. It's work

[{"first_name": "Ashok","last_name": "Parmar"}]

```
$('#dataTbl').DataTable({

        ajax:{
           url:  '/view',
           type: 'POST',
           
           contentType: 'application/json',
           success: function(data){
                
                populateDataTable(data);
           },
           error: function (e) {
                console.log("There was an error with your request...");
                console.log("error: " + JSON.stringify(e));
           }
        }//ajax

      }); // table

function populateDataTable(data) {
        $("#dataTbl").DataTable().clear();
        var row = 1;
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            $('#dataTbl').dataTable().fnAddData( [
                row,
                value.first_name,
                value.last_name 
              ]);

           row++;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you must return your json with the array of "aaData"

```
return dataTabledata['aaData'] = 'your json data'
```

By default DataTables will use the "aaData" property of the returned data which is an array of arrays with one entry for each column in the table.

In your jQuery create ajax that will handle the data from your server side

```
 function getdtData(){
    /*clear table row first*/
    $('#sample').dataTable().fnDestroy();
    /*populate your datatable using ajax*/
    $('#sample').dataTable({
    "sDom": 'frtip',
    "bServerSide": true,
     /*server side source*/
    "sAjaxSource": "rest/index.php?m=foo",
     /* we use sDom to specify the lenght of the pagination if you will using pagination in your data table*/
    "lengthMenu": [[ 5, 5], [ 5, 5]],
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "aTargets": [ 0 ], "bSortable": false},
        { "aTargets": [ 1 ], "bSortable": false },
        { "aTargets": [ 2 ], "bSortable": false },
        { "aTargets": [ 3 ], "bSortable": false }
    ]
});
```

refer to this documentation http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side

Comment: @smerny Yep enjoy coding although it was little confusing

Comment: Okay I'm not wanting to modify the data I send from the server as that would mess up some other stuff. I'll give a +1 on this for leading me to a solution that works for me though.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem while using codeigniter json_encode tipe of data, it returned a [Flat array data source](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_flat.html) afther a few days of trying

> "aaData": data,

i finaly got it working using

> "ajax": {
>               "url": "index.php/controller/function",
>               "dataSrc": ""
>           },

instead of

> "data": [
>       [
>         "Tiger Nixon",
>         "System Architect",
>         "Edinburgh",
>         "5421",
>         "2011/04/25",
>         "$320,800"
>       ],

, in reality it is quite simple [see datatble ajax documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#t1').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/controller/function",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "CCODIGOCLIENTE" },
            { "data": "CRAZONSOCIAL" },
            { "data": "PENDIENTE" },
            { "data": "siete" },
            { "data": "sietev" },
            { "data": "catorcev" },
            { "data": "catorce" },
            { "data": "veintiunov" },
            { "data": "veintiuno" },
            { "data": "mes" },
            { "data": "bimestre" },
            { "data": "trimestre" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

        <table id="t1" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>QTime</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

a few pointers for begginers...

1. make sure your script is below you libraries
2. that the number of columns matches your data
3. make your datatable id unique

good luck yaall

Answer (score 0):

The table is not populating because you have no **`data`** object in your received JSON data but referencing it *(`data` object)* for display in the table columns.

Based on your dataTable initialisation, your JSON data should look like this:

```
{"data":[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "FooBar",
    "predicted": "0",
    "points": "1",
    "section_id": "1",
    "detail_alias": ""
    ...
  },
  ...
]}
```

Comment: This would work as I mentioned in my comments, but would require me to rewrite a bunch of other code that doesn't expect the `data` field. The `aaData` field is what will work for me.

Comment: Are you trying a side server processing? Can you share your script for troubleshooting by updating your post?

Answer (score 0):

> Js Code Where json url : getjsonrequest.php

`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tableid').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            "url": "getjsonrequest.php",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "INDEX1" },
            { "data": "INDEX2" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

`

> Html Code

`

```
<table id="tableid" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Index 1</th>
                <th>Index 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Index 1</th>
                <th>Index 2</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```
var $table = $('#productListTable');

// execute the below code only where we have this table
if($table.length) {
    //console.log('Inside the table!');

    var jsonUrl = '';
    if(window.categoryId == '') {
        jsonUrl = window.contextRoot + '/json/data/all/products';
    }
    else {
        jsonUrl = window.contextRoot + '/json/data/category/'+ window.categoryId +'/products';
    }



    $table.DataTable( {

        lengthMenu: [[3,5,10,-1], ['3 Records', '5 Records', '10 Records', 'ALL']],
        pageLength: 5,
        ajax: {
            url: jsonUrl,
            dataSrc: ''
        },
        columns: [
                  {
                      data: 'code',
                      bSortable: false,
                      mRender: function(data, type, row) {

                          return '<img src="'+window.contextRoot+'/resources/images/'+data+'.jpg" class="dataTableImg"/>';

                      }
                  },
                  {
                      data: 'name'                        
                  },
                  {
                      data: 'brand'                       
                  },
                  {
                      data: 'unitPrice',
                      mRender: function(data, type, row) {
                          return '&#8377; ' + data
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      data: 'quantity',
                      mRender: function(data, type, row) {

                          if(data < 1) {
                              return '<span style="color:red">Out of Stock!</span>';
                          }

                          return data;

                      }
                  },
```