# Datatables.net is not loading any data using AJAX

Tags: ajax, datatables

I am trying to get some data from an API and load into Datatables (datatable.net). I have completed the code as per guide and it doesn't load at all.

AJAX completes the request successfully.

Code below:

```
function loadTable(api) {
$.ajax({
    url: api,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    "dataSrc": "",
    beforeSend: function () {
        console.log('\"Data collection\" query operation triggered')
        $(".overlay").show(); //We are showing loading spinner here
    },
    headers: { Authorization: 'Basic XXXX },
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        //Populate Table            
        $('#datatable').DataTable({
            "columns": [
                { "data": "DataObjectName" },
                { "data": "SourceObject" },
                { "data": "IndnexType" },
                { "data": "ObjectType" },
                { "data": "FeedType" },
                { "data": "BusinessUnit" },
                { "data": "VersionId" },
                { "data": "Unit" },
                { "data": "Unit" },
            ],
            "bDestroy": true
        })
        console.log('\"Data collection\" query operation succesfully completed');
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('\"Data collection\" query operation failed. Error : ' + errorThrown);
        showNotification('top', 'right', 'Error while performing ' + operation + '. Error : ' + errorThrown, 'danger');

    },
    complete: function () {
        $(".overlay").hide(); //We are showing loading spinner here
        console.log('\"Data collection\" query operation task completed');
    }
});
```

}

Comment: can you share the link you followed,  datatable with ajax is opposite what you did.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39693168/populate-datatable-from-ajax-json -> I followed the resolved comment in this link.
Also, I got it working, I have removed the quotes for data under columns. Please do comment if I had implemented this in a wrong way.

Comment: if you see all the answers in the link you shared, you will notice one thing, ajax is inside datatables not outside, this helps for serverside processing, . you can update your question with what you have done

Comment: @AhmedSunny Got this working with what you have mentioned. Made the ajax call within the Datatable and it did the wonders.