# I'm having a problem with the Ajax data to show in my table

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

This code seems to work as the width of the column can be seen in the view but then it failed to show the data.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadDataTable();
});

function loadDataTable() {
    dataTable = $('#tblData').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: '/admin/product/GetAll'
        },
        columns: [
            { data: 'title', width: "25%" },
            { data: 'category.name', width: "15%" },
            { data: 'isbn', width: "15%" },
            { data: 'author', width: "15%" },
            { data: 'listPrice', width: "15%" }
        ]
    });
}
```

[image]

I have tried different methods of using the ajax given by the documentation but it still shows the table but failed to show the data

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your issue and it's because we lack of identifying the datasource.

[image]

without the `dataSrc: ""`, the data table couldn't know which is the data source in the ajax response. In my mvc project, I have an action method which return a list of data.

```
public List<Data> getData() {
            var list = new List<Data> {
                new Data{ id=1,room="Basic",price="$49"},
                new Data{ id=1,room="Common",price="$59"},
                new Data{ id=1,room="Luxury",price="$99"},
                new Data{ id=1,room="Deluxe",price="$89"}
            };
            return list;
        }
```

Like you can see, when I comment that line, DataTable could get correct response but couldn't load them.

[image]

Comment: And I also found [another good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39693818) which sending ajax request to get the data first and use it  in the `data` field.